# Rounding up MULTIPLE COLUMNS to 2 decimal places using jq with awk in Bash/Shell

Tags: json, bash, awk, jq

Pls i need help rounding up multiple columns in this .csv output.
So far, i've been able to pipe my jq output into awk and round up just a single column but don't know how to round up this 6 columns.

This is the demo.json payload

```
{
  "XXXX": "XXX",
  "XXXXX": "XXXXXXX",
  "stack": {
    "123": {
      "overflow": 6014.4703
    },
    "234": {
      "overflow": 6090.3888
    },
    "356": {
      "overflow": 8973.8136
    },
    "244": {
      "overflow": 5034.4258
    },
    "789": {
      "overflow": 5957.6018
    },
    "545": {
      "overflow": 1225.7363
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the line of code i have so far for a single column roundup

```
cat demo.json | jq -r --argjson H "$(date +%H -d "1 hour ago")" '["Hours", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"], ([.stack."123".overflow/1000, .stack."234".overflow/1000, .stack."356".overflow/1000, .stack."244".overflow/1000, .stack."789".overflow/1000, .stack."545".overflow/1000] | [$H] + .) | @csv' | awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }NR>1{ $3=sprintf("%.2f", $3) }1' > demo.csv
```

What i'm trying to achieve

```
"Hour","A","B","C","D","E","F"
"09","6.01","6.09","8.97","5.03","5.96","1.23"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQ round number to two decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74152553/jq-round-number-to-two-decimal-places)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update `|=` the relevant columns / fields as follows: Divide by `10`, then `round`, and divide again by `100`.

```bash
.stack[].overflow |= (. / 10 | round / 100)
```

```json
{
  "XXXX": "XXX",
  "XXXXX": "XXXXXXX",
  "stack": {
    "123": {
      "overflow": 6.01
    },
    "234": {
      "overflow": 6.09
    },
    "356": {
      "overflow": 8.97
    },
    "244": {
      "overflow": 5.03
    },
    "789": {
      "overflow": 5.96
    },
    "545": {
      "overflow": 1.23
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/o1FWPmiFYBc)

Answer (score 0):

Add more `sprintf`s in `awk` separated by semi colons:
`... | awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }NR>1{ $2=sprintf("%.2f", $2); $3=sprintf("%.2f", $3); $4=sprintf("%.2f", $4); ...etc... }1' > demo.csv`