# JQ round number to two decimal places

Tags: json, parsing, jq

I use jq 1.6 and I try to round the number to two decimal places. How can I do it?

My code:

```
echo 20.152 | jq -c 'round'
```

My output:

```
20
```

Expected output:

```
20.15
```

Comment: Try `. * 100 | round / 100` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Cap649GbOR1) or see [Rounding up MULTIPLE COLUMNS to 2 decimal places using jq with awk in Bash/Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73153702/rounding-up-multiple-columns-to-2-decimal-places-using-jq-with-awk-in-bash-shell)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can multiply by a power of ten, round, then divide by the same power of ten. Use `100` for two decimal digits. Ignoring floating point inaccuracies, this should give you your expected number.

```
jq '.*100|round/100'
```

If you need it regularly, you can define a function and use it:

```
def round(precision):.*pow(10;precision)|round/pow(10;precision);
```

Putting the definition inside the `~/.jq` file allows you to use it in all of your jq programs automatically:

```
$ echo 20.152 | jq 'round(2)'
20.15
```