# how to round up to 2decimal in combination with %s in bash

Tags: formatting, jq

Team,
might be simple but am scratching head. if you see I am getting `0.00` instead of `59.42`. also , I want to smartly set in the %.2f inside the first var itself so that I don't have to do it separately. any hint.

```
var="$(printf '%s' "$conditions" | jq -r 'select(.metricKey=="new_coverage").actualValue')"
echo $var
echo $var | printf "%.2f"
printf "%.2f" $var
```

output

```
echo $var
59.42028985507246
echo $var | printf "%.2f"
0.00printf "%.2f" $var
```

sample conditions is below

```
{ "status": "OK", "metricKey": "new_reliability_rating", "comparator": "GT", "periodIndex": 1, "errorThreshold": "1", "actualValue": "1" } { "status": "OK", "metricKey": "new_security_rating", "comparator": "GT", "periodIndex": 1, "errorThreshold": "1", "actualValue": "1" } { "status": "OK", "metricKey": "new_maintainability_rating", "comparator": "GT", "periodIndex": 1, "errorThreshold": "1", "actualValue": "1" } { "status": "ERROR", "metricKey": "new_coverage", "comparator": "LT", "periodIndex": 1, "errorThreshold": "80", "actualValue": "59.42028985507246" } { "status": "ERROR", "metricKey": "new_duplicated_lines_density", "comparator": "GT", "periodIndex": 1, "errorThreshold": "3", "actualValue": "18.823529411764707" }
```

Comment: thanks and is there a way i can make just one expression that does all? ex: `var="$(printf '%s' '%.2f' "$conditions" |......)"`

Comment: This is apparently an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), as the question is more about `jq` than `bash`. Retagging.

Comment: `printf` does not read from stdin; you cannot pipe inte it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addressing OP's recent comments/questions about storing the `%.2f` results in `var` ...

With the `bash/printf` builtin we can make use of the `-v <variable>` option, eg:

```
$ printf -v var "%.2f" "59.42028985507246"

$ typeset -p var
declare -- var="59.42"
```

Pulling the `jq` code into the mix:

```
$ conditions='{ "status": "OK", "metricKey": "new_reliability_rating", "comparator": "GT", "periodIndex": 1, "errorThreshold": "1", "actualValue": "1" } { "status": "OK", "metricKey": "new_security_rating", "comparator": "GT", "periodIndex": 1, "errorThreshold": "1", "actualValue": "1" } { "status": "OK", "metricKey": "new_maintainability_rating", "comparator": "GT", "periodIndex": 1, "errorThreshold": "1", "actualValue": "1" } { "status": "ERROR", "metricKey": "new_coverage", "comparator": "LT", "periodIndex": 1, "errorThreshold": "80", "actualValue": "59.42028985507246" } { "status": "ERROR", "metricKey": "new_duplicated_lines_density", "comparator": "GT", "periodIndex": 1, "errorThreshold": "3", "actualValue": "18.823529411764707" }'

$ printf -v var "%.2f" $(jq -r 'select(.metricKey=="new_coverage").actualValue' <<< "${conditions}")

$ typeset -p var
declare -- var="59.42"
```

If `printf -v` is not available we could spawn an additional subprocess:

```
$ var=$(printf "%.2f" $(jq -r 'select(.metricKey=="new_coverage").actualValue' <<< "${conditions}"))

$ typeset -p var
declare -- var="59.42"
```

Answer (score 2):

Referencing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74152553/jq-round-number-to-two-decimal-places) as mentioned by [ChrisB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7204912/chrisb) already, rounding in `jq` is pretty simple - just a matter of using a multiple with the right number of zeroes, rounding, then dividing by the same number.

```
$: echo '{ "a": { "b": 123.456, "c": .54321 } }'|jq '.a.b*100|round/100'
123.46
$: var="$(echo '{ "a": { "b": 123.456, "c": .54321 } }'|jq '.a.c*100|round/100')"
$: echo "$var"
0.54
```

If for some reason you needed to establish a minimum number of zeroes *before* the decimal, you might still need the printf, but the use is a little nonintuitive - you have to give the entire field width, including the decimal character:

```
$: printf -v var "%05.2f\n" $(echo '{ "a": { "b": 123.456, "c": .54321 } }'|jq '.a.c*100|round/100')
$: echo "$var"
00.54
```

If there are more digits to the left of the decimal, it keeps them.

```
$: printf -v var "%05.2f\n" $(echo '{ "a": { "b": 123.456, "c": .54321 } }'|jq '.a.b*100|round/100')
$: echo "$var"
123.46
```

Answer (score 1):

`printf` does not read from stdin, but from it's arguments. Therefore
`echo $var | printf "%.2f"` prints "0.00", sice the first argument for `printf` is missing.

The default way to do this would therefore be

```bash
printf "%.2f" "$var"
```

If you want to store this value back into `var`, you can use

```bash
var="$(printf "%.2f" "$var")"
```

If you **really** want to us a value from stdin inside `printf`, you can use [xargs](https://manpages.org/xargs):

```bash
echo $var | xargs printf "%.2f"
```

Comment: Safe in this specific case, but in the general case be aware of [xargs-related pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#Using_xargs_without_-0) if `var` can contain characters that `xargs` might treat specially.

Comment: thank you and there is no way I can just form one expresson like fit the `%.2f` inside the `var=` instead of using separate print?

Comment: @AhmFM: If you mean including this in your first line, you can use the xargs trick I suggested:

```var="$(printf '%s' "$conditions" | jq -r 'select(.metricKey=="new_coverage").actualValue' | xargs printf "%.2f")"```

Comment: There may be some way to make `jq` output `%.2f`-formatted numbers - if that's what you want you should [edit] your question to make it clearer that you don't want a fix for `echo $var | printf "%.2f"` as all current answerers thought you wanted and tag your question with `jq` instead of `bash`.

Comment: JQ can indeed round, as already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74152553/jq-round-number-to-two-decimal-places).

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing:

```
printf '%.2f\n' "$var"
```

instead of:

```
echo $var | printf "%.2f"
```

Comment: thank you and there is no way I can just form one expresson like fit the `%.2f` inside the `var=` instead of using separate print?

Answer (score 1):

Why not round in jq directly?

```
.actualValue | tonumber*100 | round/100
```

But if you wanted to truncate with `printf`, you have to specify the variable as positional argument – `printf` cannot read from standard input:

```
printf '%.2f' "$var"
```