# convert code written in python to be compatible with jq command

Tags: jq

I have this python code that works.
But I will like to use jq command line utility so that it can be part of shell script.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open('output.txt') as f:
    x = json.load(f)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(x['Datapoints'])

df.sort_values('Timestamp')
```

---

Update:

I am getting correct output as shown below:

```
$ cat output.txt  | jq ' .Datapoints[] | {cidr: .Timestamp, comment: .Average} | join(",")' | more

"2023-06-12T08:19:00+00:00,0.18333333333333332"
"2023-06-12T04:10:00+00:00,0.03333333333333333"
"2023-06-12T07:42:00+00:00,0.03333333333333333"
"2023-06-12T03:33:00+00:00,0"
```

But I do not need double quotes and second field should be 0.18 instead of 0.1833

---

Update 2:

```
# head -20 output.txt
{
    "Label": "DBLoad",
    "Datapoints": [
        {
            "Timestamp": "2023-06-12T08:19:00+00:00",
            "Average": 0.18333333333333332,
            "Unit": "None"
        },
        {
            "Timestamp": "2023-06-12T04:10:00+00:00",
            "Average": 0.03333333333333333,
            "Unit": "None"
        },
        {
            "Timestamp": "2023-06-12T07:42:00+00:00",
            "Average": 0.03333333333333333,
            "Unit": "None"
        },
        {
            "Timestamp": "2023-06-12T03:33:00+00:00",
```

Comment: Are you asking how to print the [dataframe in JSON](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) so that you can pipe the program's output to jq?

Comment: No. I am trying to convert JSON data to csv using shell script. I am trying avoid using python.

Comment: See if [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-convert-json-to-csv-using-linux-unix-shell/) helps.

Comment: Show us `output.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the [`@csv`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#Formatstringsandescaping) filter with [`-r`/`--raw-output`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq) on a [sorted array](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#sort,sort_by(path_expression)) (and probably [apply rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74152553/112968) to numbers, if I read your question right)

```
jq -r '.Datapoints
| sort_by(.Timestamp)[]
| [.Timestamp, (.Average*100|round/100)]
| @csv' output.txt
```

Example output:

```
"2023-06-12T04:10:00+00:00",0.03
"2023-06-12T07:42:00+00:00",0.03
"2023-06-12T08:19:00+00:00",0.18
```

Comment: jq: error (at <stdin>:125): null (null) and number (100) cannot be multiplied

Comment: I got that error very rarely. Not an issue.

Comment: how to return only the rows 'where .Average > 1'

Comment: @shantanuo Use `try` or `...? // ...` pattern. Use `select` to filter rows. Please ask new questions for new problems.